# Android AppCompact v7-23 theme broken

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-support-design, android-appcompat

I am starting new android project from android studio. Below is the login screen i see . I don't know what i am missing out here.

[image]

I have no idea why is the accentColor is being shown something like this?

**build.gradle ( module level )**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:' + rootProject.ext.junitVersion
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:' + rootProject.ext.loopjHttpAsyncTask
    compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:' + rootProject.ext.bottomBar
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:' + rootProject.ext.supportLibraryVersion
    compile 'com.android.support:design:' + rootProject.ext.supportLibraryVersion
}
```

**build.gradle (project level)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

ext {
    //app related
    compileSdkVersion = 23
    buildToolsVersion = "23.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    targetSdkVersion = 23

    //android related library
    constraintLayout = "1.0.0-alpha3"
    junitVersion = "4.12"
    supportLibraryVersion = "23.3.0"

    //custom libraries
    bottomBar = "1.3.9"
    loopjHttpAsyncTask = "1.4.9"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue caused by gradle build-tool version. Changing build tool version to stable one would solve it

**replace**

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha3'
```

**with**

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
```